# Incompatible dependencies in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle-kotlin-dsl

THIS IS MY MAIN CODE

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Network;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.androidnetworking.AndroidNetworking;
import com.androidnetworking.common.Priority;
import com.androidnetworking.error.ANError;
import com.androidnetworking.interfaces.JSONArrayRequestListener;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<String> arrnames = new ArrayList<>();
        ListView list = findViewById(R.id.list);
        //aise hi library import nhi hori maven repositories and jcenter add kro
        AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        AndroidNetworking.get(url)
                .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("res",response.toString());

                        //parsing
                        try {
                            for(int i =0;i<response.length();i++){
                            JSONObject objResult = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = objResult.getString("name");
                            arrnames.add(name);
                                ArrayAdapter<String> arradaoter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrnames);
                                list.setAdapter(arradaoter);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        anError.printStackTrace();
                      Log.e("error",anError.toString());
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

THIS IS MY BUILD.GRADLE KTS CODE

```
dependencies {

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation ("com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2")
    implementation ("com.github.User:Repo:Tag")
}
```

IT IS SHOWING "Dependencies using groupId `com.android.support` and `androidx.*` can not be combined but found `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` and `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1` incompatible dependencies" ERROR

THIS IS MY SETTING GRADLE

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()

        }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()


    }
}

rootProject.name = "My Application"
include(":app")
```

IT IS SHOWING "Dependencies using groupId `com.android.support` and `androidx.*` can not be combined but found `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` and `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1` incompatible dependencies" ERROR

I AM NEW TO ANDROID DEV AND WOULD APPRECIATE YOUR HELP

I WAS TRYING TO GET SIMPLE STRING DATA FROM A ONLINE JSON URL AND EXPECTED A LIST VIEW OF THE DATA
I TRIED LOWERING TARGET SDK TO 33 AND SOME RANDOM FIXES FROM YT BUT THEY DID NOT WORK

Comment: 1) Please do no use all capitals for full sentences as that is considered shouting. 2) Check your `gradle.properties` files. You may want to try `android.enableJetifier=true` as documented: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio since one of your libraries, `com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2` is really old and I can't tell if it even maintained: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking/issues